# Is there a function similar to Eval() in asp.net razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, runtime, eval

Is there a way by which I can do somethin like this inside a Razor view:

```
<h1>Normal razor code</h2>
@Html.Action("NormalRazorCode")

@Eval(" @Html.Action(\"RuntimeEval\") ")
```

Basically a text-to-razor compiler at runtime (that doesnt create a whole new view like RazorEngine does for example).

Comment: May I know why do you need this?

Comment: First thought was inside a cms editor, to be able to have strongly typed links like @Url.Action("Post", new { id = 5}) that will be automatically updated to latest canonical url version

Comment: What's `latest canonical url version`?

Comment: could be for example `showposts/{category}/{post-alias}` . While a link of the form `postsController/postsAction/5` as a permalink would work, having a `showposts/categoryx/newest-funniest-post` is better, and is automatically updated using the latest mvc route.

Comment: I see. Why don't you use routing for this? I don't see what Eval has to do with it.

Comment: I do, but in a string you download from database you can't use routing. The workaround I have atm is post-processing like so: `@Html.RazorParse(text)` which is something like this: `text.replace(
[Url{actionName}]", Url.Action(actionName)`

Comment: The reason I want to do this is that I have a template file with placeholders I load from the database, and I want to be able to use existing partials in those database strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could assume that the views exist at compile time, and create the actual files at runtime, this way the ViewEngine will work the way it does by default

basically you could create a `Html.Eval` helper that will create the .cshtml file and after Render it using `Html.Action` or `Html.Partial`

Comment: thanks for the reply, but thats an actual new templated like razor engine with the added cost of file I/O!

Comment: asp.net reads files as well so I/O is still involved, in your case you also write them, but you could write it just once and rewrite it only when the template will change in the DB

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do something similar; I have model data (under my control) stored in a database, and it would simplify my life if I was able to include HTML helpers in those strings that could be "expanded" when included in a page.

Main motivation was to allow me to re-use existing partial views.

There's no `eval` function, but you can easily write an extension method that will evaluate methods that you choose to allow in advance.  In my case, I want to evaluate calls to `@Html.Partial()`.  The example here is pretty simple - it looks specifically for `@Html.Partial("somePartialView")` calls and replaces it with the actual partial:

```
    public static IHtmlString ExpandHtmlString(
        this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
        String html)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(html))
            return new HtmlString(html);

        const String IDENTIFY_PARTIAL = @"@Html.Partial\(""([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*)""\)";

        var partialFinder = new Regex(IDENTIFY_PARTIAL);
        var matches = partialFinder.Matches(html);

        foreach (Match m in matches) {
            var matchedStr = m.Value;
            var viewName = m.Groups[1].Value;
            var partial = htmlHelper.Partial(viewName);

            html = html.Replace(matchedStr, partial.ToHtmlString());
        }

        return new HtmlString(html);
    }
```

And you call it from your Razor page as so:

```
@Html.ExpandHtmlString((String)Model.SomeStringField)
```

You could easily expand on this to to evaluate a set of methods or operators that you decide in advance you will accept.